# Guest User cannot access @AuraEnabled Apex Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-apps, guest-user

I created a force.com Site, which uses a LWC in Visualforce page. It seems that the Guest User cannot read the records and even if I preview as admin the Site still the records are not showing. Guest User has access to the objects, the visualforce page and the Apex class controller. Is there any permission I need to add? TIA.

Comment: Do the guest users have access to records? Is there any guest sharing rule created to share records with guest users?

Comment: Hi thanks @manjit5190 for your comment. I resolved this by adding a standardController in visualforce page. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a critical update called "Restrict Access to @AuraEnabled Apex Methods for Guest and Portal Users Based on User Profile".If you have this critical update enabled in your org then the guest users will not be able to access the @AuraEnabled apex classes unless you give the access on profile level.

Please refer the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lc_restrict_apex_guest_users.htm) to see the same for more information.